# Google Contacts API Batch Delete Issue

Tags: c#, google-api, google-contacts-api, google-data-api

i'm try to delete members with groups by using batch operations for my contacts,

but i can not delete clean,

i try to find my problem, may be is [etag] setting,

but i don't know how to use [etag] in my program.

can anyone help me?

```
    public void ClearMember()
    {
        List<Contact> requestFeed = new List<Contact>();
        ContactsRequest cr = CretificateRequest();
        Feed<Contact> fg = cr.GetContacts();
        Console.WriteLine(fg.TotalResults);
        int count = 0;
        foreach (Contact contact in fg.Entries)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] id = contact.Id.Split('/');
                Contact deleteContact = cr.Retrieve<Contact>(new Uri("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/" + id[id.Length - 1]));
                deleteContact.BatchData = new GDataBatchEntryData(contact.Id, GDataBatchOperationType.delete);

                requestFeed.Add(deleteContact);
                count++;

                // Google Batch can not more then 100
                if (count != 0 && count % 95 == 0)
                {
                    Feed<Contact> responseFeedCT = cr.Batch(requestFeed, new Uri("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/batch"), GDataBatchOperationType.delete);

                    // Check the status of each operation.
                    if (responseFeedCT != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Contact entry in responseFeedCT.Entries)
                        {
                            if (entry.BatchData.Status.Code != 200)
                            {
                                log.WriteContactsLog(entry.BatchData.Id + ": " + entry.BatchData.Status.Code + " (" + entry.BatchData.Status.Reason + ")");
                            }
                        }
                        requestFeed.Clear();
                    }
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }

    }

        Feed<Contact> responseFeed = cr.Batch(requestFeed, new Uri("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/batch"), GDataBatchOperationType.delete);

        // Check the status of each operation.
        if (responseFeed != null)
        {
            foreach (Contact entry in responseFeed.Entries)
            {
                if (entry.BatchData.Status.Code != 200)
                {
                    log.WriteContactsLog(entry.BatchData.Id + ": " + entry.BatchData.Status.Code + " (" + entry.BatchData.Status.Reason + ")");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why would you be using Etag to delete?

Comment: because google say: [ The update and delete requests require gd:etag attributes to avoid overwriting another client's changes. ]
ref -> 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#deleting_contacts